# R - linear mixed model for data repeatedly measured under various conditions and time points

Tags: r, mixed-models

I'm struggling with data repeatedly measured under varis conditions & time points.

I measured a parameter called A with sonograph, before and after some intervention.

Up to this, I think I can use RM-ANOVA for this data.
but, I repeatedly measured A under various conditions like position & location

my data looks like this:

[image]

I want to prove that the A measured in visit2 is smaller than the A measured in visit1 regardless of the location and position.

so, I tried to make linear model like this:

**A ~ visit + location + position**

but there is a problem that repeated measurements on each visit are not independent, for each subject.
It means that particular location & position affects on A, so I have to apply random intercept for "location" and "position".

additionally, I have to consider "subject effect" on A.

so I changed my model like this, using random intercept for each subject:

**A ~ (1|no) + visit + (1|location) + (1|position)**

I made model above with `lmer()` function like this:

```r
lmsample <- lmer(A~visit + (1|no) + (1|location) + (1|position), data=d_sample)
summary(lmsample)
```

The result is:
[image]

My question is whether the model I made is logically and mathematically flawed.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: you can `dput(df)` that is helpful that image as people can just copy your data frame to the R IDE and run for the solution you are looking for

Comment: "I want to prove that the A measured in visit2 is smaller than the A measured in visit1 regardless of the location and position" - I think I'm missing something. Why do you need a model for that?  Don't you just want to ensure max(A) for visit2 < min(A) for visit1 (ie the largest A for visit2 is smaller than the smallest A for visit1)? Might need to group by other some other fields (`no`, for example) depending on your requirements

Comment: Thanks for your comments. 
First, for Hobo, I don't just want to show that the values ​​of visit2 are greater than visit1. To be precise, I want to see how the values ​​of visit2 of each subject change compared to visit1.

And also thanks for PesKchan!